# ListNode implementation in scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

Hi I'm a newbie to Scala, and wondering how to rewrite a simple ListNode class from Java to Scala.

In java it looks like below, and I could create a head node **head = new ListNode(0)**, and then set **head.next = new ListNode(1)**

```
// Java code
public class ListNode {
    public int val;       // data stored in this node
    public ListNode next;  // link to next node in the list

    public ListNode(int data) {
        this.val = data;
    }
}
```

But I found it's hard to rewrite the same logic in Scala, below is a case class for ListNode

```
// Scala code
case class ListNode[T](vl: T, nt: ListNode[T]) {
    def value: T = vl
    def next: ListNode[T] = nt
}
```

And it failed when I was trying to instantiate a head node, and instantiate another new node and set head.next to it:

```
scala> val head = ListNode(1, Nil)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: ListNode[?]
       val head = ListNode(1, Nil)
```

I'm thinking of put the "next list node" into Option[], to handle null cases, but it seems getting more and more complicated...is there a simple and correct way to do this in Scala?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are intermixing trait definitions and actual values. I thing the scala code you need is just:

```
case class ListNode[T](value: T, next: ListNode[T] = null)
```

Depending on use case, you might want to change `next` to `Option[ListNode[T]]` and/or define it as `var next` if you want it to be mutable.

Answer (score 1):

You mean `null`, not `Nil`. `Nil` is a `scala.collection.immutable.List`, but the `ListNode` constructor doesn't want that, it wants a `ListNode`.

Whether a null is the best way to represent the empty list is another question, but that's what you did in your Java code (`next` defaults to null), so if all you're trying to do is the exact same thing in Scala, go ahead and use a null.

Comment: Not at all! in Scala we've got `null`, `Null`, `Nothing`, `Nil`, and `None`... not to mention `Unit` which is also a nothing... nobody and no one can keep this all straight at first, believe me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can implement the list node in Scala. You could easily replace the null with `Option[ListNode[T]]` if you'd like.

```
trait ListNode[T]{
  def value: T
  def next: ListNode[T]
}

object ListNode{

  def apply[T](item: T): ListNode[T] = new SingletonNode(item)

  def apply[T](item: T, next: Option[ListNode[T]]): ListNode[T] = next match {
    case Some(node) => new Node[T](item, node)
    case _ => new SingletonNode(item)
  }

  def apply[T](item: T, next: ListNode[T]): ListNode[T] = new Node[T](item, next)

  private case class SingletonNode[T](override val value: T) extends ListNode[T]{
    val next: ListNode[T] = null
  }

  private case class Node[T](override val value: T,
                             override val next: ListNode[T]) extends ListNode[T]
}
```

Some example usage

```
val ln1 = ListNode(1)
val ln2 = ListNode(1,ln1)
val ln3 = ListNode(10, ln2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the option demo!